# Is there an easy way to convert an express app to meteor?

Tags: node.js, express, meteor

I am trying to convert a node.js with express framework app to meteor. 
Essentially doing the reverse way of https://github.com/onmodulus/demeteorizer

Comment: probably not in any automated way as the models of building Express app and Meteor app are so different.

Comment: I don't know what these people who flagged the question want. To me it's pretty cleat what the question is. If it hadn't been then how would I have been able to answer it? A question doesn't need to be long in order to be clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Definitely not automatically, but there are a bunch of tricks you can chain together to *almost* get it automatically.

I've been through just that and here are all of my tricks for this.

Let's start with your express app main .js file. This one you need to add the following at the top:

`/server/main.js`:

```
routes = {};
var app = { 
    get: function(route, foo) {
        // routes.get[route] = foo;
        routes[route] = foo;
    }, 
    all: function(route, foo) {
        // routes.all[route] = foo;
        routes[route] = foo;
    } 
};
```

All this does is to define the `app` functions you need, and record the defined routes in an object, which we will later use to define those routes using `iron-router`. So this makes sure that things like the following get recorded in `routes`:

`/server/main.js`:

```
app.get('/show', function(req, res) {
    res.render('mytemplate');
});
```

That's really the main *trick*. From here on its just labor.

In good meteor style, we will wrap all route rendering calls into a fiber, to make them synchronous like everything else on the meteor server. For that, we define a wrapping function `waiter` that we can reuse over and over again to wrap the route functions. And while we are add it, we will massage the connect request and response that we will get from the iron-routes on the meteor server into the `res` and `req` objects express would like to see. Mind you: this is not complete by any stretch. It's just the signatures I wanted to use from these objects.

`/server/main.js`:

```
/** create an sync version for meteor */
waiter = function(foo, req, res) {
    var waiter_aux = Meteor._wrapAsync(function(foo, req, res, callback) {

        res.set = function(header, value) {
            res.setHeader(header, value);
        };

        res.send = function(codeorhtml, html) {
            if (html) {
                // two arguments provided, treat as described
                res.statusCode = codeorhtml;
            } else {
                // no code, just html
                html = codeorhtml;
            }
            callback(null, html);
        };

        res.render = function(name, data, callback) {
            callback = callback || function(err, html) {
                res.send(html);
            };

            var html = Handlebars.templates[name](data);
            callback(null, html);
        };

        res.json = function(object) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify(object));
        }

        res.redirect = function(URL) {
            res.writeHead(302, {
                'Location': URL
            });
            res.end();
        };

        req.header = function(x) {
            return this.header[x];
        };

        TemplatesObject = Handlebars.templates;

        // these objects need to be extended further
        foo(req, res);
    });

    return waiter_aux(foo, req, res);
};
```

Finally, the real deal: creating routes for each specified express route. For this we will use [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router). The following code will go through each defined route (caught by our redefined `app` functions and stored in `routes`), and wrap it in a fiber using our `waiter`, which will also take care of translating between `this.request`/`this.response` and the `req` and `res` objects express apps assume.

`/routes.js`:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // create routes for all the app.get's and app.all's in bibbase.js
    // (server)
    console.log("setting routes:", routes);
    _.each(routes, function(foo, route) {
        Router.map(function () {
            this.route(route, {
                path: route,
                where: 'server',
                action: function() {
                    this.request.params = this.params;
                    var html = waiter(foo, this.request, this.response);
                    if (!this.response.statusCode) {
                        this.response.statusCode = 200;
                    }
                    if (!this.response.getHeader('Content-Type')) {
                        this.response
                            .setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
                    }
                    this.response.end(html);
                }
            });
        });
    });

}
```

---

These are the most essential things I've done to accomplish what you are asking about. I'm sure I've missed a few details here, but this should give you an idea.

---

Update for post-Spacebars (I forget which version of Meteor that was):

In order to make this work, you now need to add [handlebars-server](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router):

```
meteor add cmather:handlebars-server
```

Comment: that's a very impressive answer!