# What is the equivalent of Express res.send() in Meteor?

Tags: node.js, express, meteor, twitter-digits

I'm trying to use the **res.send()** from Express into a Meteor project without using a Meteor package like glittershark:meteor-express:     https://github.com/glittershark/meteor-express

I'm wondering if there is a solution just using Meteor rather than adding Express on top of Meteor?  In particular, how do I use **res.send()** in Meteor?
http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.send

This is the NodeJS code snippet from https://github.com/twitterdev/cannonball-web/blob/master/routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  // Send the verified phone number and Digits user ID.
  var digits = JSON.parse(body)
  return res.send({
    phoneNumber: digits.phone_number,
    userID: digits.id_str,
    error: ''
  });
}
```

One great answer posted a year ago suggests using fibers.  Meteor has undergone a lot of changes since this post and I'd like to avoid fibers:
[Is there an easy way to convert an express app to meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045986/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-an-express-app-to-meteor)

I'm adding this link to another relevant answer posted that might be helpful in anwering my question: [Porting Express App to Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562521/porting-express-app-to-meteor)

Thanks for reading.  :)

Comment: Are you trying to send this data to a meteor client, or as a rest service for any client?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm working on a Meteor accounts login package for Twitter Fabric Digit:  https://github.com/christieewen/accounts-fabric-digits   It's not ready to be published but it's kind of working right now with the package glittershark:meteor-express   My thoughts were that it seemed excessive to have Express on top of Meteor but if that's the right approach, I'm not opposed to it.  This is my first time writing a Meteor package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [many good, simple ways you can add a rest api that serves json to a meteor app](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API) (I recommend [restivus](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API#Restivus)), however the requirements you are forcing on yourself are only going to make it difficult for you.
[WebApp.connectHandlers and connect](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API#WebApp.connectHandlers%20and%20connect) is the low level apis that you can use, but you are only asking for further difficulties by wanting to avoid Fibers, as this simply is how things are done in Meteor.

Rather then trying to force square pegs into round holes, I suggest you do one of the two following options:

- [Use one of the recommended options for adding a rest api to a Meteor app](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API)
- Have a expressJS app running beside your Meteor app to serve the api, and simiply accessing the same MongoDB.

Comment: Hi JeremyK, thanks so much for your response and clarifications.  I was under the impression that Fibers are used behind the scenes in Meteor and not to be touched directly.  I'll be okay to use Fibers if that's the way to go.  I'm writing a Meteor package for accounts-fabric-digits login similar to the accounts-facebook, accounts-twitter, etc: https://github.com/christieewen/accounts-fabric-digits/tree/master/example   Given this new information, is there a particular option you'd recommend?

Comment: Fabric digits implements oath so I'd recommend looking at how the core supported oath accounts packages are written. e.g.  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/accounts-github