# What can go wrong if I run an express or http server from within a meteor app?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Say I `Npm.require('some_express_app')` inside a meteor app, and run it on some unused port for providing hypothetical special purpose service. What are the implications of doing so? What can go wrong in doing so? Is okay to `app.listen` on some port, or would it be more appropriate to `child_process.spawn` another node process for the express (or some other node server) from within the meteor app?

Comment: It will work. But I don't think it will be apporpriate.

Comment: It works I have tried, I want to know the reasons for which it might not be appropriate, or if it is A Okay

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it per se, but the questions is rather "why would you want to"? Maybe you want to just convert your express app into a meteor app? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045986/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-an-express-app-to-meteor/23048530#23048530

Comment: Let's say there are many apps already written in express, or some other node framework and I'd like to include them in my big app, but I am not sure if users will like it. So I'd rather give them a shot by just running them from within the app instead of going through the effort of porting every app to meteor.

Comment: The thing that could go wrong is releasing the port in case of Meteor server crash, though I'm pretty sure it would be taken care of. If you've tested such scenario and it works, I'd say you're good to go.

Comment: Yes i have an app where I am doing this. Server restarts and the guest app restart on same port without a problem.