# Meteor picker server side router use express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, meteor

I am trying to use express functions like `res.send('string')` or `res.json(json)` in my meteor rest api using the [picker](https://github.com/meteorhacks/picker) server side router. In the documentation, it says :

> You can use existing connect and express middlewares without any
>   issues.

**How can I use express funtions like res.send and res.json ? When I try to use them, it tells me they are not a function.**

I have the following main.js file for my server :

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Picker} from 'meteor/meteorhacks:picker';

var bodyParser = Meteor.npmRequire('body-parser'),
    methodOverride = Meteor.npmRequire('method-override'),
    logger = Meteor.npmRequire('morgan');

Picker.middleware(bodyParser.json());
Picker.middleware(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
Picker.middleware(logger('dev'));
Picker.middleware(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method'));          // Microsoft
Picker.middleware(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override')); // Google/GData
Picker.middleware(methodOverride('X-Method-Override'));

Meteor.startup(() => {
    console.log('meteor server started');

    var postRoutes = Picker.filter(function(req, res) {
        return req.method == "POST";
    });

    postRoutes.route('/post/:id', require('./routes/helloworld'));
});
```

And the following route action (routes/helloworld.js) :

```
function helloworld(params, req, res, next) {
    res.send('id:' + params.id); 
}

module.exports = helloworld;
```

I get the following error :

```
TypeError: res.send is not a function
```

It yells the same error when I try to use res.json...

packages.json :

```
{
    "body-parser": "1.15.2",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-http": "3.0.0",
    "method-override": "2.3.6",
    "mocha": "3.0.2",
    "moment": "2.14.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.5",
    "morgan": "1.7.0",
    "supertest": "2.0.0",
    "supertest-as-promised":"4.0.0",
    "express":"4.14.0"
}
```

**UPDATE** I found that I can mimic res.json with this code :

```
function helloworld(params, req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.setHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    res.end( JSON.stringify({id:params.id}) );
}

module.exports = helloworld;
```

Comment: You question is not clear. Are you getting error if you use `res.json()` or `res.end()`/`res.write()`? Those should just work out of the box. Though there is no `res.send()`.

Comment: I get an error on res.json and res.send

Comment: res.send and res.json are functions from express

Comment: Is it possible you create a github repo?

Comment: Yes, I can do that

Comment: @JohnSiu https://github.com/alexbrillant/trading-engine

Comment: I will clone and check it out, will take sometime.

Comment: you may also be interested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045986/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-an-express-app-to-meteor/23048530#23048530

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Picker/Meteor is not using express, it does not have res.send() and res.json().

However, you can explore Restivus, which is a high level api wrapper which handle json automatically.

http://meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API#Restivus

Following is the sample code from above link:

```
if(Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // Global configuration
    Api = new Restivus({
      version: 'v1',
      useDefaultAuth: true,
      prettyJson: true
    });

    // Generates: GET/POST on /api/v1/users, and GET/PUT/DELETE on /api/v1/users/:id 
    // for Meteor.users collection (works on any Mongo collection)
    Api.addCollection(Meteor.users);
    // That's it! Many more options are available if needed...

    // Maps to: POST /api/v1/articles/:id
    Api.addRoute('articles/:id', {authRequired: true}, {
      post: {
        roleRequired: ['author', 'admin'],
        action: function () {
          var article = Articles.findOne(this.urlParams.id);
          if (article) {
            return {status: "success", data: article};
          }
          return {
            statusCode: 400,
            body: {status: "fail", message: "Unable to add article"}
          };
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```